# Поверить регистр первой буквы - php

Tags: php

Подскажите как можно проверить регистр первой буквы? К примеру если первая буква в нижнем регистре сделать большим, а если регистр большой оставить как есть.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого используется функция `ucfirst`
В качестве аргумента принимает строку и возвращает эту же строку но с первым символом в верхнем регистре. Если этот символ является буквой.

```
$str = "строка";
$str = ucfirst($str);
echo $str;
//Выведет "Строка"
```

Comment: Не выведет "Строка". Проверка http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43aac1442c7f0e2b785cb2fd989fbfde3e7483d2

Comment: @Visman Там нерусская локаль, поэтому русские буквы за буквы не считаются.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да что-то я сомневаюсь, что функция предназначенная для работы только с однобайтовыми кодировками заработает правильно при смене локали в то время, как все используют UTF-8 ;)

Comment: @Visman  ну если утф8, то конечно.

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтобы сделать первую букву заглавной в строке на русском языке, предлагаю следующий код:

```
<?php
    $str = "строка";

    function upper($str) {
        $str = trim($str);
        $up = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1));
        return $up.mb_substr($str, 1); 
    }

    echo upper ($str);
```